# Не могу добавить комнтарии на php. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, веб-программирование

```
<?php
                if (isset($_POST['do_post'])) {
                    $errors = array();
                    if ($_POST['name'] == '') {
                        $errors[] = 'input name!';
                    }
                    if ($_POST['text'] == '') {
                        $errors[] = 'input text!';
                    }
                }
                if (empty($errors)) {
                    mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `comments` (`autor`,`text`,`pubdate`,`
                        articles_id`) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST[
                          'text']."', NOW(), '".$art['id']."')");
                    echo 'OK';
                }else{echo $errors[0];}         
            ?>
```

Comment: $connection ранее как-то инициализируется? не видно по коду, ошибки какие то выдает? добавьте в начало сразу после "<?php" - строку: ini_set('display_errors',1);

Comment: @EugeneEvstafiev, никаких ошибок не выдает, переменная инициализируется в (другом) раннее подключённом файле.

Comment: ```$connection = mysqli_connect(
 $config['db']['server'],
 $config['db']['username'],
 $config['db']['password'],
 $config['db']['name']
);```

Comment: можно еще так попробовать поймать ошибку: на примере другого запроса 
if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName) VALUES ('Glenn')")) {
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}

Comment: @EugeneEvstafiev, мне нужно заменить данные в условии на свои?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте отловить ошибку:

```
<?php
            if (isset($_POST['do_post'])) {
                $errors = array();
                if ($_POST['name'] == '') {
                    $errors[] = 'input name!';
                }
                if ($_POST['text'] == '') {
                    $errors[] = 'input text!';
                }
            }
            if (empty($errors)) {
                if(!mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `comments` (`autor`,`text`,`pubdate`,`
                    articles_id`) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST[
                      'text']."', NOW(), '".$art['id']."')")) {
                     echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($connection));
                } else
                echo 'OK';
            }else{echo $errors[0];}         
        ?>
```

Comment: спасибо. Ошибку нашел и исправил)